# Como carregar várias imagens na Cloudinary?

Tags: c#

Eu uso [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_integration) para fazer upload de arquivos na nuvem.

O código a seguir funciona com 1 imagem, exemplo:

```
var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
{
    File = new FileDescription(@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Pictures\Ferrai.jpg"),
    PublicId = "my_folder/images",
    EagerAsync = true
};
var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
```

Na minha pasta contem 8 imagens, como eu posso subir várias imagens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na propriedade `PublicId`, você precisa colocar um nome de arquivo diferente.

Exemplo:

- "my_folder/images/image1"
- "my_folder/images/image2"
- "my_folder/images/image3"

Segue código:

```
string[] files = 
    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Pictures\teste", "*.jpg");

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
    {
        File = new FileDescription(files[i]),
        PublicId = $"my_folder/images/{System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files[i])}",
        EagerAsync = true
    };
    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
}
```

Comment: Queima? Como assim?

Comment: E utilizando a propriedade `UseFilename` a `true`?